# Property does not exist on type 'something' in generic typed function

Tags: typescript, generic-type-argument

Why it does not work, when I am checking if the `phone` exists or not. The TypeScript should catch that and know if `phone` exists, then it must be `AddressWithPhone` interface.

Its been so long, I probably did not define the types correctly,

```
interface Address {
    street: string;
    zip: string;
    state: string;
    city: string;
}

interface AddressWithPhone extends Address {
    phone: string;
}


interface EditAddressProps<T = Address | AddressWithPhone> {
    address: T;
    onChange: (address: T) => unknown;
}

const something = <T,>(props: EditAddressProps<T>): string => {
    // Error: Property 'phone' does not exist on type 'T'
    if (props.address.phone) {
        return 'Its AddressWithPhone';
    }
    return 'Its Address without phone';
}
```

TS Playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBN1QgZx8gbwChlTkcxsIwAucy0AcwG4SyAvYABzoqidZl6cSLwYgWbUgmBgAnmP4TWAXyJFQkWIhQYsuHAHVZACwAKJgPYgUEAB6QQ6fHux5CU5Fys3FAomrqmtDwSMgAouiyrgZmUJZcOAA8ACrIALxomG74AD5Z+njGYOY+EAB8HkJw2QZ0KYJk1gDCJnASEHQAFDWFOPUAlBmVAK4gANYglgDuIKrqCNYU5JYAttQmTBnIqQA05V1c8Yl0kdG1eHEJySnlA34Sw1VkwDDIh8c4AHS9OV-e1ggQ2IQiE2DAIygIGQAHIAJJgFwXIymCyAmGNUhqMHUSHQ+GIgo5ZDTUyWEZgLxlDEBIhAA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `<T = Address | AddressWithPhone>` you are setting the default value of `T` to the union `Address | AddressWithPhone`.  You haven't actually constrained the possible values of `T` so `T` still could be anything.

You want to use `extends` to limit the possible values of `T`.  This still doesn't work perfectly with a union because `phone` is not defined on `Address`, and properties must be defined on all members of a union in order to access them.  We want a base type with all properties of `Address` required and `phone` optional.  There's a lot of ways to define that, but here's one:

```
type BaseAddress = Address & Partial<AddressWithPhone>
```

```
const something = <T extends BaseAddress>(props: EditAddressProps<T>): string => {
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/RwR8vm)

Comment: It seems to work, but any difference between `T extends BaseAddress = BaseAddress` and `T extends BaseAddress` on Line 15 of your example?

Comment: There's a slight difference but it's not really that important.  `T extends BaseAddress = BaseAddress` restricts the value AND sets a default value of `BaseAddress` if `T` is not provided.  `T extends BaseAddress` just restricts the value, but doesn't set a default, so you always need to specify the `<T>`.  I put the default value on the interface so that you can use `EditAddressProps` without the generic as well as using `EditAddressProps<T>`.  In the case of the function definition, there is always a `T` so it doesn't really need a default value.

Comment: It does not seem to work :( https://tsplay.dev/VNVAvw

Comment: Ok so what you are seeing here is that when you check the type of `props.address.phone`, you refine the definition of the variable `props` but it does not refine the definition of the type `T`.  You could add `as T` in your `onChange` as a quick fix.  https://tsplay.dev/gWo09w

Answer (score 1):

Here is alternative way to do it:

```js
type AddressBase = {
    street: string;
    zip: string;
    state: string;
    city: string;
};

type Address =
    | AddressBase
    | AddressBase & {
        phone: string;
    }

type EditAddressProps<T> = {
    address: T;
    onChange: (address: T) => unknown;
}

const withPhone = (props: EditAddressProps<any>): props is EditAddressProps<AddressBase & {
        phone: string;
    }> => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(props.address, 'phone');

const withoutPhone = (props: EditAddressProps<any>): props is EditAddressProps<AddressBase> =>
    !withPhone(props)


const something = < T extends Address>(props: EditAddressProps<T>) => {
    if (withPhone(props)) {
        const phone = props.address.phone; // string
        props.onChange({
            street: '123',
            zip: 'AB12345',
            state: 'TX',
            city: 'Dallas',
            phone: 'sdf', // phone is required here
        })
        return 'hello'
    }

    if (withoutPhone(props)) {
        const x = props.address // no phone
        props.onChange({
            street: '123',
            zip: 'AB12345',
            state: 'TX',
            city: 'Dallas',
            phone: 'sdf' // expected error, phone property is redundant here
        })
    }

    const defaultCase = props; // EditAddressProps<T>


    return 'default'

}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnAThAzigQgQxdAvFAbwCgpSoVhkJgAucygSwDsBzAbhLIC8Gw6LEzdp1IVMwCP0asOZKAGMGoKYJlEAvhyKhIsBMjRRcIqAB89SVBmwQT5%20JbRYcUAGSETcsAAsA9k0l6VWE5dSJtcGgAUTglBwMUAAVEXzAUAB4AFQA%20Iw85TH0rOkzZMn8AYW9MVkCACkLHFBKASiNcgFcmAGsmXwB3Jg4wonl-Cih%20pW9EvwC8urAUtLoYuKK0ZNSMmpBslrol7agGFCg14HirLbT0q6cbN3y5Mh9-QIEhMtJ1XNxcgDyACMAFYQeTAAB0R2Avh0EEh1RQAMGNwgiFAkPkmAANjjFssUJDGgkADRQADkbwCFJaWjGTAmU2Afg6wFm7wWRxW51ilw2SUJ6V2%200OhJOZwu90F2zuAucED%202RMAEJmTM5hACdsWuFRuNgORfABbajeIR5dJQTJQCAADwkTDgZ2l2W1PKlApuGRybX%20z1IDAAZlA6uqOQF3SgWm1iC8yAyJtS8FBuUSSVZoZq2FAAPS5oJCTyvQmQyrVWp1OPxl4CCDUOgUgCMACYAMwU0nF%20M8PiUmDoVttgAsAFZO93a8BxIEKZkABoTmsvRTKSkAEVxOOwS%20Xr01jZQcCDnbzBeTEqgyAAjh0GMg4FBvOjbMv1Lrl8hgB1EExKc%208V8CkTBGORg1DdVfDZCMtTTGMAxXA0oDtPI02JAUzygPpU01Sc0PLGoWC1as9yCetaEpIdd1I3tGwHIcx2ovcxAkRsFyY5dVxARtNzxHcu1I0hk0PY8KUw%201IAhCBH3RFJEHJC9uXRUBLwfLo4BqQ1n2QSd3xA8I5ETQ0AgAN3RVDCRzfNeXWJpvSyZUDLIL8fz-Ck4AgINMA6HFgGAjQiCAA)

If you have a deal with union types with generics, I would suggest to use typeguards, because TS is unable to narrow it as you would expect